# REST API: CRUD operations in model or controller

Tags: node.js, rest, model-view-controller, express

I'm building an app using express and mongoose. My backend is an api (since the frontend is native iOS). In an MVC framework, the controller acts as an interface between Model and View. Since I don't have Views, should I do away with the Controllers and keep my crud operations in the Models, or should I keep them in the Controllers? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

**View**

You still have a view since you'll need to display whatever the response is.

**CRUD operations**

These operations are delegated to the service layer by controllers. The service layer alters the state of the model layer.

Comment: The view is on the client, it just needs data, which my backed is sending as JSON. The operations are indeed sent to a db service, but it needs the name of the model that the operation needs to performed on.

Comment: Bart is right. If you speak in terms of MVC you still have a view in your API on the server side: Your JSON responses are the view. Your CRUD operations are basically executed by the model tear. However you will still need controllers to handle requests and trigger all required actions. But you won't necessarily need a service layer in between. Your controllers can talk to the models directly. This depends on the complexity, context and scope of your application.